# Force as a function of velocity as $t$ goes to infinity, strange result

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

Here is the question:

> "A particle with mass m is given an initial velocity $v_0$ so that it moves in a straight line (you can consider it positive). It is subject only to a force that is inversely proportional to the square of
> its speed, as $F = −c_xv^2$.
>
> (a) Write down Newton’s 2nd law for the particle, and the corresponding differential
> equation for the velocity as a function of time.
>
> (b) Integrate the equation of motion to find out v(t).
>
> (c) Integrate again to find out x(t).
>
> (d) What is the total distance the particle will travel? Why? For full marks, you
> need to explain clearly why the answer makes physical sense. Hint: What is the limit of
> x(t) when t → ∞?.

I solved the differential equation and got:

$v(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{ct}{m} + \frac{1}{v_0}}$

And

$x(t)=\frac{m}{c}ln(ct/m+v_0^-1)+x_0$

But as t goes to infinity, v approaches 0, suggesting the distance is finite, and x goes to infinity which is contradictory. Also, given that the object as an initial positive velocity and is subject to a retarding force, won't v quickly reach 0 and the object will stop moving? That's not reflected in the equations of motion.

Ok, so here's what I'm thinking. The retarding force is proportional to the square of velocity. Eventually the velocity will be $0<v<1$ and every change in velocity will lead to a smaller and smaller acceleration that approaches 0 but never reaches it (or only reaches it at $x=\infty$.

Comment: what is cx here?

Comment: @sheltonBenjamim it's some constant.

Comment: It occurs to me, isn't this a non linear differential equation?

Comment: This question might help you out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808999/why-doesnt-fx-to-0-at-x-to-infty-imply-that-lim-x-to-inftyfx

Comment: This is similar to the sum $\sum_n^\infty 1/n $. $1/n$ is decreasing but it's not decreasing fast enough for $S_n$ to converge, the sum is still divergent. This $\sum_n^\infty 1/{n^2} $ sum however converges to $\pi^2 /6$.

Comment: "a force that is inversely proportional to the square of its speed" the formula written is directly proportional, not inversely proportional. Typo in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> But as t goes to infinity, v approaches 0, suggesting the distance is finite, and x goes to infinity which is contradictory.

The position goes to infinity before the velocity starts decaying to zero fast.