# Drag force proportional to square of velocity - interpretation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

Consider an object with mass $m$, initial velocity $v_0$ subject to drag force of $-Kv^2$. The solution for the velocity is
$$
v(t) = \frac{1}{\frac{K}{m}t+\frac{1}{v_0}}
$$
and for the travelled distance
$$
x(t) = \frac{m}{K}\ln\left( 1+ v_0 \frac{K}{m} t \right).
$$
What would be the proper interpretation of such a result in the limit is infinite time? For the velocity is simple. Once the time is very long, the velocity goes to zero. What about the distance? It seems the travelled distance is infinite. How to interpret this? Is this physical, since the limit with $t\to\infty$ is infinite?

Unfortunately, the similar topic does not fully answer my question, on how to interpret such a result. With many thanks.
[Force as a function of velocity as $t$ goes to infinity, strange result](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/587689/force-as-a-function-of-velocity-as-t-goes-to-infinity-strange-result)

Answer (score 1):

The situation is similar to this graph of $v(t) = \frac{1}{t+2}$

[image]

$v(t)$ approaches zero for large $t$, but the distance, represented by the area under the graph, does not have a definite limit, but keeps increasing, in theory to any value, if $t$ is large enough.

This can happen because the velocity decreases slowly.  If the velocity were proportional to $\frac{1}{t^2}$ the area (and distance) reaches a definite limit as $t$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

In real life gravity takes care of the infinity for us, either by separating the object from the medium (the object is moving so fast that it leaves the medium behind and goes on an interstellar journey) or by getting rid of the relative velocity (the projectile falls towards center of mass of the system, the system and the projectile have an inelastic collision, and the medium comes along for the ride; e.g. the airplane crashes and comes to a stop).

The drag equation is also just an approximation and shouldn't be expected to hold up when you assign extreme values to the variables.